# Excel VBA macro gives unexpected results?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that loops through a sheet (Sheet4) to place data in another sheet (Ark7). The 'rKvartal' varaiable is a text string fetched from a third sheet (Ark4). Only if the two criterias in the outer loop is met will it go to the inner loop. This part works. My problem is that the macro lists data from the inner loop that is not less than or equal to the 'rKvartal' variable. (This has to be done in a macro) The macros looks like this:

```
Dim C, C2 As Range
Dim rKvartal As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Ark7.Columns("B:F").ClearContents
    
    cValOffset = 101
    cVal = 2 'row# where data in rLog (ark7) goes to
    rKvartal = Sheet3.Range("AP24") 'Criteria to filter data
    
    'Create headers for use in the list being created
    Ark7.Cells(1, 2).Value = "ID"
    Ark7.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Sansynlighed"
    Ark7.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Konsekvens"
    Ark7.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Sum"
    Ark7.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Kvartal"
    
    For Each C In Sheet4.Range("W15:W114")
        If C = "Risk" Or C = "Occured" Then
            For Each C2 In Sheet4.Range("K15:K114")
                    If C2 <= rKvartal Then
                        'All cells that are either a risk or occured and that is less than or equal to e.g Q4 2021
                        Ark7.Cells(cVal, 2).Value = C.Offset(0, -21).Value
                        Ark7.Cells(cVal, 3).Value = C.Offset(0, -15).Value
                        Ark7.Cells(cVal, 4).Value = C.Offset(0, -14).Value
                        Ark7.Cells(cVal, 5).Value = C.Offset(0, -13).Value
                        Ark7.Cells(cVal, 6).Value = C.Offset(0, -12).Value
                        cVal = cVal + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
            Next C2
        End If
    Next C
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("rLog").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("rLog").Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=Range("E2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("rLog").Sort
            .SetRange Range("B2:F100")
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
    Ark7.Activate
    Ark7.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(8, 6)).Select 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Ark7.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(8, 6)), , xlYes).Name = "RisikoSorteret" 'Laver en tabel eller liste
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RisikoSorteret").TableStyle = "Tabeltypografi 3" 'Giver listen en typografi
End Sub
```

[image: Data . unexpected result]

[image: Data source]

Answer (score 0):

`rKvartal` is a string variable, so numeric comparitives ('less than' or 'more than') won't work as they only work on numbers and dates.
If the text string `rKvartal` *means* a numeric or date value, consider using `CDec()` or `CDate()` to get that value.
Alternatively, if `Sheet3.Range("AP24")` will contain a number or date rather than text, just change the variable type;

```
'Change
Dim rKvartal As String

'To any one of the below:
Dim rKvartal as Long     'Integer
Dim rKvartal as Date     'Date
Dim rKvartal as Double   'Decimal
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to Dim the 'rKvartal' to date and 'Sheet3.Range("AP24")' representation is indeed a date, but the result is unfortunately still the same...

Comment: what do you mean 'representation' ? Does the cell have an excel date value, or simply text that means a date? (to find out, try changing the cell's number format; if it will let you change into different formats such as short date, long date or numeric value, it's a date value; if not it's text).

Comment: If the cell value is text rather than a date value, you'll need to change `rKvartal = Sheet3.Range("AP24")` to `rKvartal = CDate(Sheet3.Range("AP24"))`

Comment: The cell in sheet3.range("AP23") is an unformatted date so it is represented by a number e.g. 44105 for Oct. 1st 2020. The C2 variable in the data source sheet is also a unformatted date represented as a number - so in my book Im comparing apples-apples as stepping through the code shows me 44105 <= 44105 --> despite this I still get the same result.

Comment: Ok - the only thing I can suggest then is to continue stepping through the code until it starts doing wrong things, and at that point check the variables to see which is wrong. You'll probably want to comment out the 'application.screenupdating=false' so you can see what's going on on the sheet. I'm struggling to identify anything else that should make that code give an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The inner loop was redundant. It just needed the criteria and not another loop:

```
    For Each C In Sheet4.Range("W15:W114")
        If C = "Risiko" Or C = "Indtraf" Then
            If C.Offset(0, 1).Value <= rKvartal Then
                'Alle risici der opfylder kriterierne
                Ark7.Cells(cVal, 2).Value = C.Offset(0, -21).Value
                Ark7.Cells(cVal, 3).Value = C.Offset(0, -15).Value
                Ark7.Cells(cVal, 4).Value = C.Offset(0, -14).Value
                Ark7.Cells(cVal, 5).Value = C.Offset(0, -13).Value
                Ark7.Cells(cVal, 6).Value = C.Offset(0, 1).Value
                cVal = cVal + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C
```